# How to preprocess Twitter Bootstrap LESS files into aggregated style file using default theme?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using **Twitter Bootstrap 3** in my new project and I'd like to **NOT** embed bootstrap's classes in my HTML markup (to avoid coupling with the framework). So I decided to use **LESS** as described [here](http://ruby.bvision.com/blog/please-stop-embedding-bootstrap-classes-in-your-html).

I tried something like:

```
nav {
 .navbar;
 .navbar-fixed-top;
 .navbar-default;
}
```

It works as expected but I can't apply *theme.less* from Bootstrap's distribution. Is there a way to do it gracefully?

Comment: what do you mean by *can't apply*? what are you trying to do? what errors (if any) do you get? can you post a code example?

Comment: @MichałRybak I mean that that my page looks like default _flat_ bootstrap page (styles from theme.less are totally ignored). I tried to import _theme.less_ before the _bootstrap.less_, after it, and instead of it - nothing works for me. I'm new in HTML/CSS. maybe I missed something?

Comment: what file do you import it to? what *nothing works* mean - are there any errors during compilation to CSS? note that `theme.less` itself imports `variables.less1 and `mixins.less`, make sure they are in the same folder with `theme.less`.

Comment: I've just took a look at my theme.less and it looks broken. I checked out bootstrap again and now the page looks better but it seems that theme doesn't override all the styles - active navbar menu item is too dark (theme makes it lighter). The same effect I have using CSS when definition of bootstrap-theme.css appears before bootstrap.css in HTML.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your problem now. Can you post some code samples?

Comment: ok, I have bootstrap _less_ folder contents unpacked into my _less/bootstrap_ folder. In the _less_ folder I also have 3 files: _nav.less_ (which is listed in question), _main.less_ which contains body top padding and _styles.less_ with: `@import "bootstrap/bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/theme";

@import "main";
@import "nav";` and it looks like ![this](http://s10.postimg.org/72vamtg6h/actual_menu.jpg)

Comment: and how should it look? Be *precise* about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default theme.less will be compiled in a different theme.css file. So theme.less is not imported in bootstrap.less.

So for example compile this:

```
@import "variables.less";
@import (reference) "mixins.less";
@import (reference) "navbar.less";
@import (reference) "utilities.less"; // for pull-left()
@import (reference) "forms.less"; // for form-inline()
@import (reference) "theme.less";

nav {
 .navbar;
 .navbar-fixed-top;
 .navbar-default;
}
```

The resulting CSS will style your nav as defined by .navbar-default in theme.less.

**Note** import theme.less after navbar.less